# phone crashing constantly

Tags: crashes, logging, terminal, emulators

can you help me discover what is causing my phone to crash?

I've been having this problem for a while now but it seems to be getting worse. it happens at random and is almost like a RAM seizure.
the phone will freeze completely. whatever previous images will become suspended on screen and any audio playing will go into a stutter loop until either I yank the battery or it restarts on its own

I need to know whether this is hardware related, or if is an app causing problem or some kind of malware. how can I find a log or something to show what happened right before crash?

phone is a Samsung Illusion, SCH-i110 with 2.3.6 gingerbread

SuperSU pro and terminal emulator installed

Comment: For the starter, could you explain what do you mean by "phone crashing"? Does an app crash inside Android (successfully booting), or the phone suddenly freeze/shutdown/reboot?

Comment: sometimes it freezes and restarts on its own , other times it freezes and I have to pull the battery

Comment: Integrate these info from comment to the question by editing it. Also, what is your device model and Android version?

Comment: I put in the details